# How to choose only positive values?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which contains positive, negative as well as NA values. How could I select positive-only values using a script? I would also like to replace negatives numbers with `NA` and leave NA values as they are.

Comment: What did you try ? What does your dataset look like ?

Answer (score 12):

You could use the `which` function:

```
sample <- c(1, 2, -7, NA, NaN)
sample[which(sample > 0)]
[1] 1 2
```

> For negative values assign NA.

Using `which`:

```
sample[which(sample < 0)] <- NA
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Since you are a new user, saying "thank you" is discouraged in Stack Overflow. If this answer solves you problem, you can upvote it and/or accept it as correct (the green tick next to an answer). Take a look at the tour located here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

And of course, have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following command:

```
> x<-c(1,2,3,-5)
> x[x>0]
[1] 1 2 3
```

would return all the positive values.
To replace negative numbers with NA use

```
> x <- ifelse(x<0, NA,x)
> x
[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Another way to select positive values would be to use `sign`

```
x[sign(x) == 1]
```

---

and we can combine both these in `Filter`

```
Filter(function(i) i > 0, x)

Filter(function(i) sign(i) == 1, x)
```